For a federal US civil case, is the process server required to list his fees or is that option?
I notice that the "Proof of Service" form (AO440), for federal civil cases contain a line for the server to list his fees.
Is this required? Can the party and the server agree to an undisclosed amount? Is this line in the form because of a particular law or is it just for convenience?


Maybe it affects whether the server's fee is eligible to be recovered as part of costs, if this party wins the case?

@NateEldredge right that's part of what I'm wondering. If it's not filled out, is it just forfeited as a potential claim to costs, or is it an actual violation of a rule?
